# Are leather safety gloves washable?

Tags: safety

[image]

Are these gloves washable? If not how do I clean them?

Comment: If you wash your gloves, everybody at the jobsite will laugh at you.  You wear your gloves until they wear out, then you get a new pair.

Comment: Ahahah there isnt "everybody" I just work in my shed as an hobby, since money is tight I dont want to always buy new pairs, I dont even know the price of these gloves are they cheap? (someone gave a new pair to me)

Comment: why do you think they'll work better if they're clean?  If there's mud on them, let it dry, them slap the gloves together to knock the dirt off.

Comment: I suppose if there's something like actual poo on them I'd want to wash them, or toss them and use a new pair. :)

Comment: Ahahah Craig :P  Well I will use them dirty then and when they get really really dirty I will just replace them :P Btw are they expensive? As I said it wasn't me who bought them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leather and/or pigskin gloves are washable:

- knock loose dirt/soil from them
- while still wearing them, apply a dollop of mild dishwashing soap to the palm of one glove then rub them together with cold water and rinse; a brush can be used for extreme soiling
- lay them out flat to dry, indoors or out (do not machine dry them)
- the washing/drying process can make them stiff so after they are dry, apply saddle oil, Neet's Foot oil, mineral oil, saddle soap, or some type of oil that won't go rancid. This will make them supple again.

A good pair of leather gloves will last for years if you take care of them.

Comment: I prefer to use saddle soap for washing leather, personally. Made for the job.